# How would my node.js application access an uploaded image on react?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mobile, expo

I am working on a react mobile application where the user can take an image with their camera and then my node application can do image processing on that uploaded picture, finally information is sent back to the react side from the node application. The problem I'm currently receiving is that I'm not really sure how to get my node application to access the taken photo.

Would the only way to do this would be to save the photo into some database and then have my node application access it there? Would it be possible to do this without saving the photo to a database?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

you could storage the taken photo using a database,but it depends of your requirements if you don't need to have an historical from your image processors (like receive a image X  from user USERNAME and it was processed as image Y ).

If you just need to make the process the photo you can send it as **base64** string encoded, so you can make a **POST** request and send that string in a JSON field from your React app to Node.js and when you receive that string you need to decode the message to generate an image, next you cold make your image processing and finally send that image as was received before

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. The one question I have is that do I need to have my node application than keep on running waiting for requests or can I have the react js app call it to start up and then close?

Comment: Well if you make an REST API it would works as if you request some resourse and then express dispatch your request, so in that case you don't have any thread o loop waiting for an special request you just define your payload.
I thing also depends of your app and how do you want to approach it, you could use aixios to handle external request